# Imprimir etiquetas HTML con PHP

Tags: php, html

Tengo este código:

```html
$html = array(
'<div id="grupo"><span>5</span><p>Invitacion de boda calendario 1</p><p>Cantidad : 1</p></div>',
'<div id="grupo"><span>6</span><p>Invitacion de boda calendario 2</p><p>Cantidad : 1</p></div>',
'<div id="grupo"><span>7</span><p>Invitacion de boda calendario 3</p><p>Cantidad : 1</p></div>',
);
```

Al imprimir me salen todas las etiquetas, como hacer para que me imprima los valores de la variable `$html` en formato HTML

Comment: hola lo que tu deseas,  es que te imprima solo el contenido que esta dentro del div.

Comment: Correcto, solo el contenido que esta pero sin las etiquetas HTML, es este momento me imprime todo y etiquetas.

Comment: Si quieres solo el contenido te deje ahí el ejemplo en la respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer que solo te muestre el contenido y no las etiquetas, tienes que usar el método de **php** ***strip_tags***. El cual te elimina las etiquetes del **html** y te deja solo el contenido. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<?php      
   $html = array(
            '<div id="grupo"><span>5 </span><p>Invitacion de boda calendario 1</p><p> Cantidad : 1</p></div>',
            '<div id="grupo"><span>6 </span><p>Invitacion de boda calendario 2</p><p> Cantidad : 1</p></div>',
            '<div id="grupo"><span>7 </span><p>Invitacion de boda calendario 3</p><p> Cantidad : 1</p></div>',
            );

    $printer='EPSON L355 Series';
    $enlace=printer_open($printer);

    for($i=0; $i < count($html); $i++){
         printer_write($enlace, strip_tags($html[$i]));
    }
    printer_close($enlace);
     ?>
```

Comment: Ejemplo: $body = "<b>Mario</b>";

$html= echo strip_tags($body); Me mostraría Mario en Negrita?

Comment: No si quieres que te muestre en negrita tienes que usar la etiqueta <b> Mario </b> pero ahí si no puedes quitar las etiquetas html porque cuando lo muestra en la página no te lo colocaría

Comment: No funciona Yoel,  error 500; para imprimir el contenido estoy usando la funcion printer

Comment: tu tienes tu página php recuerda colocar dentro de las etiquetas <?php  ?> este código.

Comment: Si copias todos este código en la página php y lo ejecuta ya te da el contenido limpio el echo ya se encarga de imprimir

Comment: Tu estas usando algún framework o lo estas haciendo de cero

Comment: la funcion print imprime todo lo que ve sin formato

Comment: Estoy usando un Framework pero acepta codigo PHP arbitrario. Le explico un poco, la función printer ejecuta una variable, ejemplo $body e imprime todo lo que hay dentro de dicha variable. Yo inserté HTML dentro de la variable pero me imprime las etiquetas y no reconoce el formato HTML. Que puede ser?

Comment: Que framework estas usando. Si colocas el código en un script aparte vas a ver que te funciona tienes que ver lo que esta sucediendo cuando lo colocas en el framework. EL error 500 que me comentas es cuando existe algún error en el código y puede ser la forma en que lo estas insertando o que no se este imprimiendo el contenido en el lugar correcto checa eso por favor.

Comment: estoy usando Telerik Grid

Comment: $html = "Impresión automática desde la impresora escogida";

$printer='EPSON L355 Series';

$enlace=printer_open($printer);

printer_write($enlace, $html);

printer_close($enlace); -> Imprime lo que hay dentro de HTML pero no me toma el formato HTML.

Comment: Funciona super pero aún tengo ese problema con el formato HTML

Comment: pues nada tienes que intercalar el código que quita las etiquetas html dentro de esto que me colocas aquí si gusta edito la pregunta para veas como es y si puedes también para enriquecer tu pregunta colócalo en la tuya. Y porque no te toma el formato html por eso lo quieres quitar las etiquetas.

Comment: De acuerdo Yoel, muchas gracias; muestrame

Comment: Ya te hice la modificación del código. te la cabo de actualizar

Comment: Gracias Yoel, pero sigue igual; <div id="grupo"><span>5 </span><p>Invitacion de boda calendario 1</p><p> Cantidad : 1</p></div> Imprese eso

Comment: Te le hice una modificación por que me falto colocar un método para limpiar las etiquetas puedes probar por favor.

Comment: Bravo men, Gracias me ha funcionado!

Comment: Muy bien, ahora quiero saber si es posible utilizar hojas de estilo en las etiquetas html.

Comment: Puedes formular una pregunta con lo que deseas para tener la idea de lo que quieres hacer. Me alegro que te allá sido de utilidad mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma fácil de imprimir arrays es con un ciclo.

Ya sea con **For**, **While** o **Foreach**.

Te dejo un ejemplo con Foreach:

```
<?php
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($array as &$valor) {
    echo $valor;
}
?>
```

Te dejo la documentación de PHP para imprimir con [Foreach](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas solo los valores la mejor opción es usar strip_tags para eliminar las etiquetas HTML, pero si deseas depurar viendo la salida puedes usar var_dump();

```
var_dump($html);
```

Comment: Ésto, en lugar de ser una respuesta nueva, debería ser un comentario/edición en la respuesta aceptada

Comment: Por ejemplo, var_dump me funcionaría si utilizo hoja de estilo para que formatee una tabla que está dentro dentro de la variable $html ? @LSCV